# Why I can configure my email on Outlook mobile but not on Outlook desktop?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, license

I have recently joined an organization as an consultant. Here I am not able to configure my Office 365 email to Outlook on my office laptop. However, I can configure it on my personal phone after device registration.

This seems very weird. This is what support person replied which I am not able to understand.

```
For contractors, the license only allows access to cloud (virtual) apps NOT desktop apps. 
You can download Outlook mobile (for phones) or access services on the web. 
But we will not be installing or licensing desktop versions of Office, Outlook etc for contractors
```

Does that mean Outlook mobile is like hybrid app which has web running in backend?

Is there any resolution to that issue? Outlook is already installed on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

The company’s response says they will not supply you one of their Office licenses. That likely makes sense for them.

If you have your own Office / Outlook license, then explain that to the company and see if they will let you have a Company Outlook profile (which does take an additional license). You already have Mobile access.

If you do not have Office installed on your own computer, you may wish to obtain an Office license. I have been in my own business for years and have my own computer and software to avoid the issue of customer practices and customer software.

If they will not allow you to have a profile for your own desktop, then there is not much else you can do.

Comment: so it requires extra license for desktop version but not for mobile application? sorry. I am not able to understand this. How is I am able to register my mobile but not desktop.

Comment: You have your own license for Office, so it should not cost the company anything . I just noted at the top that they may not know you have your own license and so ask them about making a profile.  My initial comment was to outline what they might think. So ask them about using your setup.

Comment: I don't have personal licence. it's working on my mobile without any license.  I was wondering how is this possible. that it can work on my mobile but not on my laptop

Comment: You may wish to get your own Office license so you can manage situations like this

Comment: so what you are saying is office license is only applicable for desktop version of outlook but not mobile version, is that right?

Comment: Mobile phones can generally be set up for Exchange but Outlook is the main desktop app for Exchange.